# Will installing Ubuntu wipe my Windows applications off?

Tags: system-installation

If I have Microsoft Office installed on my Windows 8 laptop, will installing Ubuntu OS wipe Microsoft Office and my other apps?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you install Ubuntu over your Windows 8 partition. You do not lose programs when installing Ubuntu, but you can lose your operating system if you are not careful.

Make sure you are aware that [Windows 8](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2086883) is more tricky to install Ubuntu.